# How to find application version

Tags: powerbuilder

One of our application developed by power builder and we don't know how to find the application version build by on which version of power builder. Can you know how to find application version and it was windows based application.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere there should be a PBVMxxx.DLL file (probably in the installation folder of the application).  The 'xxx' will give you the version.

Comment: Hi,

yes i got it . Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the Powerbuilder version via Powerscript :

```
string ls_PBver
environment env
GetEnvironment(env)

ls_PBver = string(env.pbmajorrevision) + '.' + &
           string(env.pbminorrevision) + '.' + &
           string(env.pbfixesrevision)
```